# Adjust line height when text breaks into 2 lines

Tags: css

I have a box which has text. The text is dynamically added. It can be one word, one sentence or it can break into multiple lines.

In the box however I will only display a maximum of 2 lines.

The text in the box needs to be vertically and horizontally centered. Which is where I have the problem.

What I have so far, the text is horizontally centered but not vertically centered. I tried using `display: flex` which fixes the problem for a single line text but doesn't give me the desired result when there are two. I need it to show the first two lines.

Below is the code I have so far:

```css
.item {
  width: 245px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  Some Text
</div>

<div class="item">
  Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text
</div>

<div class="item flex">
  Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text
</div>
```

If I have a way to set styles based on whether a line is broken into two I can simple set two different line-heights. `40px` for one and `20px` for the other.

How do I get the text to vertically and horizontally center without fiddling with the line-height which I need for cutting the text off at 2 lines?

Answer (score 0):

Try using **TABLE CELL** property for vertical alignment.

```
<div class="table">
 <div class="item cell">
    Some Text
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table{
    display:table;
}
.table .cell{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with padding like,

```
.item {
  width: 245px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
```